# Unknown Database type: Delphi program, DTA and IDX File Extension for Database

Tags: database, delphi

I got some databases which I cannot open. The original program seems to be a Delphi (7?) application and it uses some db1.dta, db1.idx, db2.dta, db2.idx database files.

I tried MS Access on them and DBISAM from ElevateDB (current 4.30 version, not the old ones) but without any luck.

The IDX files seem to be index files but that doesn't help me.

Any idea which database that could be?

Hex Editor tells me that the first 4 bytes of the file are "FF FF FF FF" (DTA and IDX).

It's really DTA, not DAT so it's not a typo.

Note: The database access code/libs seem to be compiled into the executable because you don't need to install anything, just run the executable and it works.

Comment: Why do you think it's build with Delphi 7?

Comment: In delphi it can be anything... from a local database file, embedded SQL engine, embedded plain databases to plain file containing records, like `var x: file of TMyRec`, so there's no meanings to associate this to any type of file just by knowing the product was built in Delphi, and the list of candidates is huge.  I'm afraid this is a guess work by trial and error to discard candidates from that list.

Answer (score 1):

.DTA isn't an extension I can find for anything, and [Wotsit](http://www.wotsit.org) doesn't know anything about it either.

The .DTA extension doesn't really mean anything, however. I can name a dBASE III .DBF file, for instance, .TXT or .RXA or .JOE and open it with dBASE, as long as I specify the extension as part of the filename. The same applies with most other software.

.IDX could be Paradox, dBASE IV, or FoxPro (among probably others) if it's an actual vendor's extension for an index. Again, though, it could be anything.

The `FFFF` doesn't really indicate anything, either, AFAICT. It's not Access, dBASE, Paradox, or DataFlex (just a check because it used .DAT for an extension).

You'll need to dig into the file with a hex editor and see if you can find out anything more from the files, I'm afraid. Simply guessing and trying to open them with various software products won't work unless you just get lucky.

Comment: I have found several mentions of "Chain link database" as the user app for .dta extension. But that is a specific app, with apparently two specific .dta files, so probably not a general database format and as such not used by OP's app. No information on the format either.